# How to retrieve records in two different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

a_ro_header, a_vehicle

in a_ro header i want to generate cust_code, cust_name, last_service_date

then, in a_vehicle i want to generate cust_code, plate_number,

how can i generate by using cust_code as primary ID?

Comment: You should look into https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just modify "inner join" to suit the type of join you want.

```
select a.cust_code,a.cust_name,a.last_service_date,b.cust_code,b.plate_number
from a_ro_header as a
inner join a_vehicle as b on a.cust_code=b.cust_code
```